# Jquery Ajax: value failed to return outside the success scope

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a strange problem here **(May be the silly one)**.

In the below code I declare the variable **retVal** and assigned null to it.
On the successful execution of code and I reassigned it with the return value (msg.d).

It successfully show the value at **alert(retVal + " divyansh");** but when I tried the same at **alert(retVal + " divyansh again");** I got null.

I know I can get the value by putting the "return retVal" inside the success but I want to know why this happen and if there is way to return the value at the bottom.

```
function getGrpParent() {
var retVal = null;
var hidType = $('[Id$=hidType]').val();
var hidGpId = $('[Id$=hidSelectedId]').val();
if (hidType == 'gp') {
    var url = "../User/UserHierar.aspx/GetParentGroup";
    var option = {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({ GroupId: hidGpId }),
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d != "") {
                retVal = msg.d;
                alert(retVal + " divyansh");
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('error');
        }
    };
    $.ajax(option);
}
alert(retVal + " divyansh again");
return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. The `return` at the bottom executes before the ajax call has finished, so the `return` in the success function doesn't actually return **to** anything. You'll need to restructure your code to use callbacks or a `deferred` object.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to move the variable retVal outside of the scope of just your function, to make it global. The success function as Jason correctly points out above is executed in its own context, outside of the scope of getGrpParent().

I hope this helps.

P.S. You should ask Jason to create an answer and accept it.